# Linkedin Company Account API Keys

Tags: api, linkedin-api

i am using linkedin api for sign in with linkedin feature in our website. currently we have a dummy account on linkedin for sign in . We also have our main COMPANY account on linkedin . so my question is , is it possible to have API Keys for any COMPANY account. if yes , where can i get that.??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to have a general company API key or use a company page to generate a key. Only individuals can create API keys

The way LinkedIn has set it up instead is to allow multiple users to have administrator access to the main key you have set. This way you can have multiple developers have granted access to view the keys and use them.

Also, be wary of creating multiple accounts or even dummy accounts. Its against the LinkedIn TOS: http://www.linkedin.com/legal/user-agreement (Section 7.2)

Comment: Just to add some information, it is possible to create API tests account. However, they have to be easily recognizable.